# Facebook query language - long query

Tags: facebook, get, facebook-fql, long-integer

I need to run quite long query using FQL. The only way I found in facebook docs is passing it using GET method. Unfortunetely as far as I know, most web servers doesn't accept urls beyond some specified length.

So the question is - what's the max url length facebook can handle? Is there any way to send the FQL query via POST so the limit can be avoided?

Comment: Sure, but the url length limit still applies. I don't want to split it into separate http requests.

Answer (score 0):

At the front end, Facebook servers run a LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySQL, and PHP) stack with Memcache (source: [see here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/facebook-work-nuts-bolts-technology-explained/)) With the Apache your url length limits to approximately 4,000 characters. However the Internet Explorer can handle only up to 2,083 characters before throwing an error message (source: [see here](http://www.boutell.com/newfaq/misc/urllength.html)).
If you want to get sure whether your query works, you need to test it in the [test console](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/fql.multiquery/) (scroll down a little).

Comment: The browser has nothing to do, the query is launched from a script. Is there any way to bypass the limit?